# iOS Swift2.2 reachable host IP

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm trying to check if the localhost is reachable

```
 private static func checkHostaviable(){
    if ([[Reachability, reachabilityWithHostName,:"google.com"],currentReachabilityStatus] == false) {

    NSLog("not available");
    }
    else{
    NSLog("available");
    }
    }
```

but its not really working..

any idea?

Comment: What's with the random commas in your code?

Comment: You're also mixing Objective-C and Swift

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regular way, and the google way (in Swift):

```
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus:NetworkStatus = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus()

    if  (networkStatus != NotReachable)
    {
        print("has access")
    }
    else
    {
        print("no access")
    }

    // Google explicit:
    let networkStatusGoogle = Reachability.init(hostName: "google.com").currentReachabilityStatus()
    if  (networkStatusGoogle != NotReachable)
    {
        print("has access to google")
    }
    else
    {
        print("no access to google")
    }
```

The Objective-C way is [well documented by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html), but at this point you should be using Swift.

Comment: hmm sorry I'm new to swift/iOS development.. have still little problems understanding the syntax. Your code doesnt work for me.. where should I implement this? Appdelegated? or directly in the reachability class?

Comment: I need to add error handling (try&catch) and (networkStateHost != Reachability.NetworkStatus.NotReachable) instead of (networkStatusGoogle != NotReachable) but still not working, now every host is reachable

Comment: Reachability does not throw any exceptions for you to catch.  Reachability status is one of three values:  NotReachable = 0, ReachableViaWiFi, ReachableViaWWAN.  You can check for these three enums if you like in your code.    Generally people call Reachability before network calls, but they also have a model where you can subscribe to Reachability status changes (see Apple's sample app).